# Configurable index name in Spring data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Data ElasticSearch repository and I like to give a default index name for production and another one for testing

Here the application.properties for production:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

Here the configuration application-test.properties

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
elasticsearch.index.name=registry-test
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

The  elasticsearch.index.name does not seem to be taken in account. What is the right setting in the properties if I am using Spring Boot autoconfiguration? I cannot find any info in the Spring documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[This is full list of properties Spring boot understands](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). You'll need to scroll down to find Elasticsearch related properties. Your property is not listed.

There is one, which may help you:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.*= # Additional properties used to configure the client.
```

But I don't know how it's working. So I guess best option for you would be to create Elasticsearch beans explicitly and not rely on auto-configuration.